# Controlar ejecución y salida de función Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tengo el siguiente bloque de código, que ejecuta una llamada y recibe un valor `(data)` correctamente. Ahora yo quiero guardar cada elemento de `data` en la variable `listaTurnos` mediante `array.push`.
Como pueden ver, hay dos `console.log`, uno que esta por fuera del `ajax` y otro que esta por dentro. 
Mi problema es que primero se ejecuta el de afuera (arroja 0) y luego se ejecuta el de adentro (arroja 2).

Yo quiero mantener mi variable `listaTurnos` cargada al salir de la funcion `ajax` para poder trabajar con dicha variable, pero siempre está vacía.

> A su vez, si yo creo una variable dentro del `success` el `ajax`, por ejemplo `var listaTurnos2 = listaTurnos;`, cuando salgo de la funcion `ajax` y quiero hacer referencia a la variable `listaTurnos2` me marca como que la variable no existe.

```
var listaTurnos = [];
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax/turnos2.ajax.php',
        dataType: "json",
        data: { item: "a" },
        success: function(data) {
            readData(data);
        },
        error: function(data) {
        }
    });
    function readData(data) {
        data.forEach(e => {
            listaTurnos.push(e["datos"])
        });
        console.log(listaTurnos.length)
    }
});


console.log(listaTurnos.length)
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que el metodo $.ajax viene con async = true por defecto, esto hace que tu segundo console.log se ejecute sin esperar la respuesta de tu ajax, te recoumiento que coloques **async: false** para evitar este inconveniente. Así, primero ejecutará tu código ajax y luego tu console.log.

Con respecto a lo de la variable dentro del Ajax o dentro de la función, te recomiendo que estudies más sobre los scopes en JavaScript ya que al declarar una variable dentro de una función esta misma no funciona fuera de ella. Lo que puedes hacer es como hiciste con el listaTurnos y declarar una variable en el scope global para poder usarla dentro del ajax.

EDIT: Otra cosa que no te había explicado es que el código ajax que estás ejecutando dentro del **$(document).ready** se ejecuta solo hasta que la página ya haya cargado, esto trae como consecuencia que tu console.log que se encuentra fuera de esta función no obtenga el resultado que esperas, para que aprendas más acerta de los Scopes te recomiendo este artículo.

https://platzi.com/blog/como-funciona-el-scope-en-javascript/

```
var listaTurnos = [];
var listaTurnos2 = [];

$(document).ready(function() {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'backend/api/utils.php?fun=obtenerColor',
        dataType: "json",
        data: 'id=' + 1,
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            readData(data);
        },
        error: function(data) {
        }
    });
    function readData(data) {
        data.forEach(e => {
            listaTurnos.push(e["datos"])
        });
        console.log(listaTurnos.length)
        listaTurnos2 = listaTurnos;
    }

    console.log(listaTurnos.length)
    console.log(listaTurnos2.length)

});
```

Comment: Ahora voy a probar lo que decis, de todas maneras lo solucione metiendo la llamada a ajax adentro de una promesa, y en el resolve guardo lo que necesito en el localStorage. Ahi funcionó correctamente, ya estoy trabado en el siguiente inconveniente jaja. En unos ratos pruebo esto, que mas alla que no lo vaya a usar puede ser una buena solucion para mas adelante. Gracias